# How do I convert table column data from 'LastName, FirstName' to 'FirstName LastName' in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

How do I convert table column data from 'LastName, FirstName' to 'FirstName LastName' in Postgres.

So if the table column contains 'Ona, Lisa' I want it to return 'Lisa Ona'. If the column doesnt contain a ' ,' then I want it to return null. I've been trying to use postgres functions SUBSTRING and REGEXP_REPLACE but cannot get anything working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `strpos` and `substr` functions and a `CASE` to return `NULL`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN strpos(name,', ') > 0 
            THEN substr(name,strpos(name,', ') + 2)  ||' ' || substr(name,0, strpos(name,', '))
            ELSE NULL END
    FROM person
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d72db/1)

Comment: Thanks Ive marked your answer correct although Ive worked out an alternative myself now, not sure which is best.

Comment: Actually sorry error in my original question I dont want it to return NULL if not valid I don't want the row returned at all

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind worked out a solution using SPLIT_PART function

```
SELECT 
t1.sort_name,
split_part(t1.sort_name, ', ', 2)|| ' ' || split_part(t1.sort_name, ', ', 1)  
FROM artist t1
WHERE 
t1.sort_name LIKE '%, %'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select split_part(name,',',2) ||' '|| split_part(name,',',1) as "thename" from tblname     
where name LIKE '%,%'
```

[***String Functions and Operators***](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) and  [***PostgreSQL SPLIT PART***](http://coderlearner.com/PostgreSQL_SPLIT_PART)